# Crear variables de sesión con Asp .Net Core2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estoy creando un programa con Telerik Asp .Net Core y me gustaría usar variables de sesión para guardar variables en concreto (tipo usuario, permisos, etc.).

(En todos los casos que pongo la palabra "usuario" es una variable ya existente)

He probado con:

```
Session["Usuario"] = usuario;
```

Pero me dice "El nombre 'Session' no pertenece al contexto actual".

También he intentado

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Usuario"] = usuario;
```

Pero me da el siguiente error "'HttpContext' no contiene una definición para 'Current' ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión 'Current' que acepte un primer argumento del tipo 'HttpContext' (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)"

Estas son las importaciones que tengo

```
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using SimpleJSON;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

(He probado más pero ya ni recuerdo cuales)

He estado buscando algún paquete de NuGet que sea fácil de utilizar y sea compatible con Core2 pero no he encontrado nada...

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Y `HttpContext.Session.SetString` has probado?

Comment: Lo he probado y me funciona pero hay variables que son arrays o datatables y, según he leído, no se pueden almacenar de esa forma sin transformarlos (cosa que no puedo hacer porque los necesito en ese formato)

Comment: Prueba con esto: http://www.talkingdotnet.com/store-complex-objects-in-asp-net-core-session/. Si te funciona comentamelo para que añada una respuesta, ya que puede ser util a mas gente

Comment: Lo he probado en un DataTable y este es el resultado: `'ISession' no contiene una definición para 'SetObject' ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión 'SetObject' que acepte un primer argumento del tipo 'ISession' (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)`

Comment: Has creado los métodos de extensión que se indican en el post que te he puesto? debes crear SetObject y GetObject en una clase estática

Comment: ¡Vale! He mirado tantas cosas durante el día que me he saltado esa parte. Sí que ha funcionado, ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya funcionado. He añadido una respuesta, ya que me parece que puede ser muy util para bastante gente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En ASP.NET Core se disponen de 3 métodos para almacenar variables de sesión. Éstos son `Set`(que espera un array de `byte`), `SetInt32` y `SetString`, y sus correspondientes métodos de recuperación `Get`, `GetInt32` y `GetString`.

Si necesitamos almacenar un objeto complejo como un `DataTable` por ejemplo, una opción es serializar el objeto (usando la librería Json.NET por ejempo).Para ello, podemos crear una clase estática y añadir los siguientes métodos de extensión:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void SetObject(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Una vez tenemos los métodos de extensión definidos, es sencillo almacenar objetos complejos en una variable de sesión:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetObject("ObjetoComplejo", dataTable1);
```

y recuperarlo:

```
var dataTable1= HttpContext.Session.GetObject<DataTable>("ObjetoComplejo");
```

---

<sub>Fuente [Store complex objects in ASP.NET Core Session](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/store-complex-objects-in-asp-net-core-session/)</sub>

<sub>Relacionado: [Introducción al estado de sesión y aplicación en ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x)</sub>

Comment: Todo funciona perfectamente pero cuando intento hacer el GetObject de un objeto complejo me da un error: "Los argumentos de tipo para el método 'SessionExtensions.GetObject<T>(ISession, string)' no se pueden inferir a partir del uso. Pruebe a especificar los argumentos de tipo explícitamente. "

He estado buscando como arreglarlo pero no llego a entender del todo el error...

Comment: Intenta especificar el tipo en la llamada. Si quieres recuperar un datatable, llamalo asi `HttpContext.Session.GetObject<DataTable>("objeto")`

Comment: Vale, con lo básico que es y no se me había ocurrido... Ahora sí funciona perfectamente. ¡Muchísimas gracias!