# Como crear una sesión en .Net core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Desarrolle un sistema con login con EntityFramework, pero ahora que cambie a .Net Core en la parte de crear mi sesión cuando no funciona con `Session["usuario"] = usuario;`

```
        if (usuario.UsuarioN != "")
        {
            Session["usuario"] = usuario;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Pero me dice que no existe en el contexto actual. También leí que se podía crear con `HttpContext.Current.Session["usuario"] = usuario;` pero me sigue sin funcionar, alguien sabe o me podría decir como puedo crear sesiones en .net core.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151521/301324

Answer (score 0):

Añado la forma en como lo resolví y espero le pueda ayudar alguien.

-Lo que yo hice fue agregar `HttpContext.Session.SetString("Usuario", usuarioLog.Usuario1);` después de que el usuario se haya logueado de manera correcta.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(Usuario usuario)
    {
        string contraMayus = usuario.Contrasena.ToUpper();
        contraMayus = ConvertirContra(contraMayus);

        Usuario usuarioLog = usuarioORM.Usuarios.Where(x => 
            x.Usuario1 == usuario.Usuario1 && x.Contrasena == contraMayus).FirstOrDefault();
        
        if(usuarioLog == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Hubó algun error, revisa tus accesos!";
            return View();
        }

        //Guardar información en una sesión
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Usuario", usuarioLog.Usuario1);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Inforperfil", usuarioLog.Inforperfil);

        Response.Cookies.Append("UltimaConexion", DateTime.Now.ToString());

        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
    }
```

Y ya solo en mi vista coloco lo siguiente:

```
@if (Context.Session.GetString("Usuario") != null)
{
   .....HTML text
}
else
{
  <h1 class="display-1 text-center">Tienes que iniciar sesión para poder 
  ver el contenido</h1>
}
```

Nota: recuerden que el nombre que esta entre comillas en `Context.Session.GetString("Usuario")` tiene que ser el mismo nombre que se le dio en `HttpContext.Session.SetString("Usuario", objUsuario);`